# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied after ssl

Tags: nginx, ssl, debian, certbot

Hi after do the ssl via the certbot  for my domain(using nginx)  and when i run my application to see it one the browser i got this error:Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/project/bin/trytond", line 83, in <module>
    **ssl_args)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1052, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1005, in inner
    fd=fd,
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 848, in make_server
    host, port, app, request_handler, passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 766, in __init__
    self.socket = ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 661, in wrap_socket
    **kwargs
  File "/user/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1216, in wrap_socket
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: Your application does not have permission to access either **certfile** or **keyfile**. Typically, certfile is readable, keyfile is usually readable only by root. Check the user and group that you are running your application as and then adjust the group permissions to allow your app to be able to read the required SSL certificate files.